# Beginner template

Tags: templates

I just downloaded TexWorks using MikTex. I am trying to write my math homework in Latex form but I am having difficulty getting the correct template. My template looks like this:

```
\title{}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{}


\end{document}
```

How can I insert my questions in LaTex form? For example, right after the date I want to have "{question 1(in bold)} ... {answer to question 1} ... {question 2(in bold)} ... {answer to question 2}" so on and so forth to the very last question?

Comment: The LaTeX wikibook might be a good place to start: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: I would rather recommend using the `exam` document class that comes with MiKTeX (via CTAN)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in several ways. Here's one possibility using theorem-like structures defined with the help of the [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\newtheorem{ans}[que]{Answer to question}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{ans}{\addtocounter{que}{-1}}
\title{Assignment}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{que}
\lipsum[4]
\end{que}

\begin{ans}
\lipsum[4]
\end{ans}

\begin{que}
\lipsum[4]
\end{que}

\begin{ans}
\lipsum[4]
\end{ans}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the previous solution I made the assumption that each question was immediately followed by its answer; a solution with more freedom might be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\newtheorem{answ}{Answer to question}

\newenvironment{ans}[1]
  {\setcounterref{answ}{#1}\addtocounter{answ}{-1}\begin{answ}}
  {\end{answ}}

\title{Assignment}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{que}
\label{que:foo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{que}

\begin{que}
\label{que:bar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{que}

\begin{ans}{que:bar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{ans}

\begin{ans}{que:foo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{ans}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this approach, you label each question (using the standard `\label` command), and then use the string used for the label as a mandatory argument for the `ans` environment.

Comment: Also, I want the symbol $\mathbb{R}^n$ to show but my latex says it doesn't recognize that form? What other forms are there for that symbol?

Comment: @Q.matin load `amssymb` in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`): `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: I tried using your template and it says I must install the new package but I clicked on install and nothing happened? Do you know why?

Comment: @Q.matin I haven't used MikTeX for many years now, so I cannot help you with this. In any case, it seems that you installed the basic version of MiKTeX; you should install the complete version, so you won't be bothered with installation of missing packages.

Comment: @Q.matin It may be that there is a long delay; I had a difficulty with MiKTeX where I thought it wasn't installing packages-on-demand, but it was actually just taking a long time to do so.

Comment: @lain Gotcha. When it asks to install what "package will it install from"?